Input devices taking a long time to work for login screen
I recently installed KDE-plasma on my arch system, and I am having an extremely annoying problem. Whenever I reboot, grub recognizes my keyboard input instantly, but when it gets to the login screen it takes about a minute for the keyboard and mouse input to start working. My keyboard and mouse are connected by usb. With the guidance of chatgpt, I wrote a script that resets my usb devices:
#!/usr/bin/env fish
for device in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/authorized
        echo "0" > $device
        echo "1" > $device
end

sudo modprobe -r usbhid
sudo modprobe usbhid

This script causes the keyboard and mouse to disconnect and not work for seemingly the same ammount of time they don't work on the login screen. When I run `sudo dmesg -w' and then run my script, I get this output for dmesg while the keyboard and mouse are disconnected (except for the last two lines, which always appear right after the mouse that I am constantly wiggling starts working):
[ 1122.351839] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 13
[ 1122.352350] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 14
[ 1122.352353] usb 1-6.2: USB disconnect, device number 16
[ 1122.352354] usb 1-6.2.2: USB disconnect, device number 19
[ 1122.397471] hid-generic 0003:258A:002A.0007: can't resubmit intr, 0000:00:14.0-6.2.4/input0, status -19
[ 1122.446122] usb 1-6.2.3: USB disconnect, device number 22
[ 1122.508655] usb 1-6.2.4: USB disconnect, device number 23
[ 1123.005104] usb 1-11: USB disconnect, device number 15
[ 1123.011062] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1123.011092] hub 1-0:1.0: 16 ports detected
[ 1123.013025] usb usb1: authorized to connect
[ 1123.013113] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1123.013133] hub 2-0:1.0: 10 ports detected
[ 1123.015936] usb usb2: authorized to connect
[ 1123.033664] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
[ 1123.157732] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[ 1123.157738] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[ 1123.160617] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[ 1123.307087] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=048d, idProduct=5702, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 1123.307101] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1123.307106] usb 1-5: Product: ITE Device
[ 1123.307111] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: ITE Tech. Inc.
[ 1123.312456] hid-generic 0003:048D:5702.0009: hiddev96,hidraw0: USB HID v1.12 Device [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
[ 1123.434053] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd
[ 1123.576378] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice=60.90
[ 1123.576393] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 1123.576398] usb 1-6: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[ 1123.578778] hub 1-6:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1123.579142] hub 1-6:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 1123.703990] usb 1-11: new high-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[ 1123.845829] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice=60.90
[ 1123.845843] usb 1-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 1123.845848] usb 1-11: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[ 1123.847794] hub 1-11:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1123.848087] hub 1-11:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 1123.920599] usb 1-6.2: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[ 1124.010984] usb 1-6.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a40, idProduct=0801, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1124.010998] usb 1-6.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 1124.011004] usb 1-6.2: Product: USB 2.0 Hub
[ 1124.012134] hub 1-6.2:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1124.012188] hub 1-6.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 1124.133932] usb 1-14: new high-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
[ 1129.264313] usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1144.836750] usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1145.339852] usb 1-14: new high-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[ 1150.596409] usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1166.172638] usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1166.279184] usb usb1-port14: attempt power cycle
[ 1166.355609] usb 1-6.2.2: new high-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
[ 1166.476391] usb 1-6.2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=328f, idProduct=003f, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1166.476402] usb 1-6.2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[ 1166.476407] usb 1-6.2.2: Product: HD Webcam eMeet C960
[ 1166.476410] usb 1-6.2.2: Manufacturer: EMEET
[ 1166.476413] usb 1-6.2.2: SerialNumber: SN0001
[ 1166.480157] usb 1-6.2.2: Found UVC 1.00 device HD Webcam eMeet C960 (328f:003f)
[ 1166.482505] usb 1-6.2.2: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 5 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 1).
[ 1166.482631] usb 1-6.2.2: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 12 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 1).
[ 1166.490822] input: HD Webcam eMeet C960: HD Webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2.2/1-6.2.2:1.0/input/input30
[ 1166.495908] usb 1-6.2.2: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[ 1166.782194] usb 1-14: new high-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[ 1171.805560] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1177.138570] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1177.345219] usb 1-14: device not accepting address 31, error -62
[ 1177.745157] usb 1-14: new high-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[ 1182.898412] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1188.231524] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1188.438055] usb 1-14: device not accepting address 32, error -62
[ 1188.438357] usb usb1-port14: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 1188.528072] usb 1-6.2.3: new low-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[ 1188.642930] usb 1-6.2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c077, bcdDevice=72.00
[ 1188.642946] usb 1-6.2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1188.642951] usb 1-6.2.3: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[ 1188.642955] usb 1-6.2.3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 1188.648293] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2.3/1-6.2.3:1.0/0003:046D:C077.000A/input/input31
[ 1188.648735] hid-generic 0003:046D:C077.000A: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2.3/input0
[ 1188.741319] usb 1-6.2.4: new full-speed USB device number 34 using xhci_hcd
[ 1188.851937] usb 1-6.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=258a, idProduct=002a, bcdDevice=10.39
[ 1188.851952] usb 1-6.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1188.851957] usb 1-6.2.4: Product: Gaming KB 
[ 1188.851960] usb 1-6.2.4: Manufacturer: SINO WEALTH
[ 1188.859498] input: SINO WEALTH Gaming KB  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2.4/1-6.2.4:1.0/0003:258A:002A.000B/input/input32
[ 1189.062197] hid-generic 0003:258A:002A.000B: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [SINO WEALTH Gaming KB ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2.4/input0
[ 1189.065075] input: SINO WEALTH Gaming KB  System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2.4/1-6.2.4:1.1/0003:258A:002A.000C/input/input33
[ 1189.125064] input: SINO WEALTH Gaming KB  Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2.4/1-6.2.4:1.1/0003:258A:002A.000C/input/input34
[ 1189.125270] input: SINO WEALTH Gaming KB  Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2.4/1-6.2.4:1.1/0003:258A:002A.000C/input/input35
[ 1189.125768] hid-generic 0003:258A:002A.000C: input,hiddev97,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [SINO WEALTH Gaming KB ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2.4/input1
[ 1189.292728] usb 1-6.2.2: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[ 1189.297446] usb 1-6.2.2: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[ 1190.179103] usb 1-6.2.2: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 12 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 3).
[ 1190.181524] usb 1-6.2.2: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 12 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 3).

Notice how after [ 1129.264313] it starts to give some errors with the code -110. It spent a long time on these, so I think these errors are causing much of the delay. Also, at [ 1171.805560] the lines that include the word "timeout" also took a long time. If I could fix these errors and prevent these timeouts, I think that would remove a significant amount of the delay.
I have tried adding this line to grub:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"
I tried switching the environment to xorg instead of wayland on the login screen and rebooting, I have tried linux-lts, I tried changing the bios setting for uhci handoff to disabled, switching display managers, plugging into every usb port my computer has, disabling autosuspend in grub, and creating a file called /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb.rules with the line:
ACTION="add, SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="258a", ATTR{idProduct}=="002a", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="on"

and none of it has helped at all.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think you found the right smoking gun, usb 1-14 and error -110, but need to further isolate which device this is that is causing the issue. Look into lsusb and /sys/bus/usb/devices/ to try and identify the 1-14 device causing the issue. It may also help to isolate the issue by only using the USB keyboard, connected directly to the motherboard. Disconnect all other USB devices and hubs, which may include your case front panel USB connection. Update the post with any further findings.

When I run lsusb, on bus one the devices are numbered 1-7, 10, and 13. There is no decice 14. I wonder if that’s the problem. Arch may be trying and failing to connect to a usb device that doesn’t even exist. When I list /sys/bus/usb/devices/ there are no directories labeled 1-14.

I tried just reinstalling arch because this issue is so annoying and it still happens. On a new install where I downloaded only a few packages and never deviated from the arch installation guide, this issue happens. I’m worried this issue will now happen on every computer I try to use. Am I cursed or something? How do I get rid of a curse? There’s no other explanation.

I have been trying all day to fix this bug and it’s driving me crazy. Unfortunately, my arch system doesn’t have a gui anymore so I can’t copy/paste any outputs I get from rust to this website. I did discover that 1-14 seems to be a port, not a device. I tried several ways of disabling the port altogether, by changing the grub file, adding a udev rule, blacklisting xhcd, and messing with the bios settings, but dmenu shows that my computer is still stupidly trying to access that 1-14 port and waiting for it to respond before throwing an error. Nothing even connects to 1-14.

1-14 doesnt show up in lsusb or lsusb -t or /sys/bus/usb/devices, but it is still causing problems

Somebody please help me. I just want to be able to turn on my computer without having to wait two minutes on the login screen for my keyboard to connect. Why the fuck does the keyboard work for grub but then it doesn’t work after grub? Did the computer forget how to register the keyboard? Why can’t the keyboard just keep working the whole time?

Something similar happens when booting from my linux install usb. It shows a few errors that say something about error -110 and read/64, which delays the startup quite a bit.

I kind of fixed it! I just added a service that waits until the keyboard is connected before starting the terminal or the display manager. There is still a delay, but it is much more bearable now that I am not just sitting on the login screen while the keyboard isn't working like it's supposed to. Now it takes longer to boot, but when it does, the keyboard works right away! It would be nice to be able to just eliminate the delay, so if anyone has any ideas, feel free to let me know. But for now, this works well enough.
